# Configure package on python

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm curious if anyone here has been able to successfully access NREL's wind datasets using the h5py library as explained here: https://github.com/NREL/hsds-examples ?

I am having trouble with configuring HSDS. I am using Python 3.7.10 and Anaconda. These are the steps that are listed:

For this to work you must first install h5pyd:

```
pip install --user h5pyd
```

Next you'll need to configure HSDS:

```
hsconfigure
```

and enter at the prompt:

```
hs_endpoint = https://developer.nrel.gov/api/hsds
hs_username = None
hs_password = None
hs_api_key = 3K3JQbjZmWctY0xmIfSYvYgtIcM3CN0cb1Y2w9bf
```

How can I configure HSDS? When I enter `hsconfigure' in the terminal I see an error "command not found." Is this happening because I used pip to download?

Any recommendations? I've never had to configure anything on Python so I'm quite lost here and not really sure where to start.

Comment: `pip show --files h5pyd | grep hsconfigure`

Comment: I find the use of `--user` flag odd - that is inappropriate for Conda environments (installs outside the environment). Not including that and making sure the `pip` corresponds to the one your environment might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. A couple questions: 1) for PhD what should I see expect when I run grep hsconfigure? I am not getting any results for this. the terminal has been running this for over 10 minutes. 2) for merv: To clarify your statement, does this mean that if I install something with pip --user, I may not be able to use it with the packages I installed with Conda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it running with the following setup:

0. (optional) [MambaForge base](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge). Mamba is faster than Conda, and working in **base** is practically an anti-pattern.
1. Jupyter in dedicated environment.

   **jupyter.yaml**

   ```yaml
   name: jupyter
   channels:
     - conda-forge
   dependencies:
     - jupyter
     - nb_conda_kernels
   ```

   **Commands**

   ```bash
   mamba env create -n jupyter -f jupyter.yaml
   ```
2. HSDS in a dedicated kernel env.

   **hsds.yaml**

   ```yaml
   name: hsds
   channels:
     - conda-forge
   dependencies:
     # core requirements
     - python=3.9 
     - ipykernel  # enables use in jupyter

     # dependencies and modules used in notebooks
     - h5py
     - pandas
     - scipy
     - pyproj
     - pytz
     - matplotlib
     - seaborn
     - requests

     # install h5pyd from PyPA
     - pip
     - pip:
       - h5pyd
   ```

   **Commands**

   ```bash
   mamba env create -n hsds -f hsds.yaml
   mamba run -n hsds --no-capture-output hsconfigure
   ## follow instructions
   ```
3. Clone repo and launch Jupyter in it.

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/NREL/hsds-examples.git
   cd hsds-examples
   conda activate jupyter
   jupyter notebook
   ```
4. Navigate to notebook (.ipynb), select **hsds** as kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the help merv!  I'm a little confused here. First, did you create a new environment on Anaconda to run this code?  What is jupyter yaml? Should I uninstall h5pyd and reinstall it without running the "--user"?

Comment: Also, pip installed h5pyd in a "hidden" folder: ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages do you know why this happened and if it will be a problem later on?

Comment: @FuturePhD that’s what the `--user` flag does (installs in hidden central location). Yes I would remove that. Really, with Conda you do not want any `python*` directories under `~/.local/lib`.

Comment: thanks merv! your suggestions and ideas were really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but I had the same issue. I got it to work by finding the path for hsconfigure then running it with the full path name.

```
pip show h5pyd | grep "Location:"
```

Using that location, find hsconfigure full path

```
find /Users/myUserName/Library/Python/3.11 -name hsconfigure
```

Then run hsconfigure directly by using the full path. For me the path was:

```
/Users/myUserName/Library/Python/3.11/bin/hsconfigure
```

This brought up the endpoint prompt. Hope it helps someone else.